# ¿Cómo funciona un archivo .ASP y cómo puedo acceder por url, si está en un servidor?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp

Estoy aprendiendo recién todo lo que es javascript, jQuery y me encontré con el método `ajax()` para mandar peticiones y recibir respuestas de un servidor, y en la w3schools.com hay un ejemplo de jQuery con el método `POST()`, en donde se mandan datos a un servidor que contiene un archivo ASP para recibir una respuesta concreta, en este caso son sugerencias o suggestion para completar una frase. Dejo el ejemplo en código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input").keyup(function(){
        var txt = $("input").val();
        $.post("/demo_ajax_gethint.asp", {suggest: txt}, function(result){
          $("span").html(result);
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Start typing a name in the input field below:</p>
    First name:

    <input type="text">

    <p>Suggestions: <span></span></p>
    <p>The file used in this example (<a href="demo_ajax_gethint.txt" target="_blank">demo_ajax_gethint</a>) is explained in our Ajax tutorial</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

En este ejemplo en el apartado de Suggestion aparece una frase de acuerdo a la inicial que se ingrese en el input, dejo el [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_post2) del ejemplo para que puedan revisarlo bien. Mi problema es que cuando intento acceder al contenido del archivo .ASP solo me aparece "no suggestion" cuando debería aparecer todas las sugerencias de palabras posibles. En el mismo código se puede ver que explican lo que contiene el archivo .ASP , pero muestran su contenido desede un archivo .txt

```
<%
    response.expires=-1
    dim a(30)
    'Fill up array with names
    a(1)="Anna"
    a(2)="Brittany"
    a(3)="Cinderella"
    a(4)="Diana"
    a(5)="Eva"
    a(6)="Fiona"
    a(7)="Gunda"
    a(8)="Hege"
    a(9)="Inga"
    a(10)="Johanna"
    a(11)="Kitty"
    a(12)="Linda"
    a(13)="Nina"
    a(14)="Ophelia"
    a(15)="Petunia"
    a(16)="Amanda"
    a(17)="Raquel"
    a(18)="Cindy"
    a(19)="Doris"
    a(20)="Eve"
    a(21)="Evita"
    a(22)="Sunniva"
    a(23)="Tove"
    a(24)="Unni"
    a(25)="Violet"
    a(26)="Liza"
    a(27)="Elizabeth"
    a(28)="Ellen"
    a(29)="Wenche"
    a(30)="Vicky"
    
    'get the "suggest" parameter from URL
    q=ucase(request.querystring("suggest"))
    
    'lookup all hints from array if length of q>0
    if len(q)>0 then
      hint=""
      for i=1 to 30
        if q=ucase(mid(a(i),1,len(q))) then
          if hint="" then
            hint=a(i)
          else
            hint=hint & " , " & a(i)
          end if
        end if
      next
    end if
    
    'Output "no suggestion" if no hint were found
    'or output the correct values
    if hint="" then
      response.write("no suggestion")
    else
      response.write(hint)
    end if
    %>
```

Pero cuando se ejecuta el código y utilizo el depurador de Chrome me aparece que estoy recibiendo datos del archivo .ASP y cuando me dirijo al archivo por medio del url que me arroja el depurador, no aparece todo el contenido. Dejo pantallazos para que se entienda mejor

[image: La consola muestra la carga del archivo .ASP al consultar una inicial en el input]

Se puede ver que hago una consulta con la inicial "a" que arroja como resultado la carga al archivo .ASP donde dice `XHR ha terminado de cargar: POST "https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_gethint.asp".` que incluso al hacer clic en el enlace me muestra detalles de la respuesta del archivo y claramente dice que he recibido los nombres "Anna, Amanda"

[image: Respuesta del archivo .ASP]

Lamentablemente el depurador no me deja explorar más allá de la respuesta del archivo .ASP, pero cuando copio el url del archivo y lo pongo en el navegador solo aparece "no suggestion" aunque modifique el url y ponga el data de la petición en ella que sería "suggest=a" lo que dejaría la url así: `https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_gethint.asp?suggest=a`

[image: Archivo .ASP solo muestra no suggestion todo el tiempo]

¿Alguien me podría explicar cómo funciona el archivo .ASP? Ya que no me arroja los datos que aparecen en el ejemplo del archivo de texto y tampoco me aparece la repuesta que me arroja el depurador de Chrome ("Anna, Amanda"). Obviamente el problema es que no sé acceder al contenido del archivo, dado que no soy experimentado en código, pero sí me gustaría entender el proceso que hay de fondo.

Comment: Lo que debe estar pasando es que el archivo .txt no es el mismo que está en .asp.

Comment: Hola que tal. desde el codigo se accede al archivo .asp no al .txt, por eso pienso que debe haber una manera de acceder al archivo .asp

Comment: Lo que te digo es que el contenido de demo_ajax_gethint.asp y demo_ajax_gethint.txt no son lo mismo (se debieron haber equivocado). El txt está el código para que funcione con GET, cuando en el ejemplo publicado en ASP funciona con POST. No hay manera de descargar el ASP y ver el código habría un problema de seguridad monumental si se pudiera hacer eso.

Comment: Creo que te voy entendiendo, tal vez se equivocaron, pero en la pagina aseguran que lo que hay en el txt, es lo que hay en el .asp, y yo pensaba que de alguna manera se podia acceder al .asp y verificar que tiene el mismo contenido que el .txt, y bueno también me dices que es imposible descargar y acceder al contenido del .asp,  nada que hacer entonces.

Comment: En el txt pone q=ucase(request.querystring("suggest")) y debería ser q=ucase(request.Form("suggest")).

Comment: Mira, tienen otro ejemplo con un archivo .asp y con el método post() aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp en donde el archivo .asp muestra mediante su url (Dear Donald Duck. Hope you live well in Duckburg.)  pero en la publicación aclaran que en el archivo .asp se ejecuta este codigo:

<%
dim fname,city
fname=Request.Form("name")
city=Request.Form("city")
Response.Write("Dear " & fname & ". ")
Response.Write("Hope you live well in " & city & ".")
%>

Tambien estan equivocados en esa publicación?

Comment: Ahí parece que está bien, se envía como POST y se recibe como POST. En cambio en el otro se envía como GET y se recibía como POST.  Sabes la diferencia entre POST y GET?? Pregunto, porque señalabas que estabas partiendo. Además, a modo de comentario, ASP (clásico) es una lengua muerta, hoy es más practico aprender griego antiguo

Comment: Amigo disculpa la tardanza, y si estoy recien partiendo con eso, me gusta averiguar lo que hacen las funciones y acceder a su codigo cada vez que puedo, usar el depurador de chorme y esas cosas, sobre el metedo post y get, se lo muy basico en realidad y gracias por aclararme que asp(clasico) ya no se usa jajajaj igual lo imaginaba ya que intente buscar maneras de acceder pero nada jajajaja